# reusing array.map() in React.js

Tags: reactjs, arrays, mapping

I can't find an answer in "many similar questions", sorry I'm new to react.
I have the following code inside `return` of my `sfc` that works/renders fine:

```
{data && allToDos && completed === 'all' && data.map(data => {
        key++;
        return (
            <div key={key}>
                <h2>{data.title}</h2>
                <p className="apart">
                    Nr: {data.id} <span>Status: {!data.completed && <span>Not </span>}completed</span>
                </p>
                <h3>User: {data.userId}</h3>
                <br/><hr/><br/>
            </div>
        );
    });}
```

Now, I have 3 different options for `completed` and in each case i want to render different set of data, so i have isolated the `data.map(data => {/*code*/})` into a separate function inside the same component,like that:

```
const dataMap = () => {
    data.map(data => {
        key++;
        return (
            <div key={key}>
                <h2>{data.title}</h2>
                <p className="apart">
                    Nr: {data.id} <span>Status: {!data.completed && <span>Not </span>}completed</span>
                </p>
                <h3>User: {data.userId}</h3>
                <br/><hr/><br/>
            </div>
        );
    });
}
```

and then i passed that function inside `return` like that:

```
{data && allToDos && completed === 'all' && dataMap()}
```

and nothing is rendered, but no error messages either.

Comment: I'd recomment to prepare the data to display first with `useMemo` which will have an array of data and `completed` in its dependency array and will return the filtered array to match the condition. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73757327/how-to-display-different-tables-on-click-in-react) for more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning from **dataMap()** function it returns **undefined** .

try this

```
const dataMap = () => {
return data.map(data => {
    key++;
    return (
        <div key={key}>
            <h2>{data.title}</h2>
            <p className="apart">
                Nr: {data.id} <span>Status: {!data.completed && <span>Not </span>}completed</span>
            </p>
            <h3>User: {data.userId}</h3>
            <br/><hr/><br/>
        </div>
    );
});
```

}